Hibernate JPA fails to cascade persist MxN relationship with Class
The title is confuse I will try to clarify.
I've class A and B that have MxN relationship. However as this relationship has attributes I needed to create a class AB to hold the relationship.
I've set all attributes of this relationship to cascade.PERSIST, however when I try to create a new class A holding a new class AB with a new class B [all mentioned are Transient] the transaction fails with some
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not set field value [SHORT_CIRCUIT_INDICATOR] value by reflection : [class br.com.fisgar.crm.model.entities.PersonClientLead$ID.clientLead] setter of br.com.fisgar.crm.model.entities.PersonClientLead$ID.clientLead; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value [SHORT_CIRCUIT_INDICATOR] value by reflection : [class br.com.fisgar.crm.model.entities.PersonClientLead$ID.clientLead] setter of br.com.fisgar.crm.model.entities.PersonClientLead$ID.clientLead
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:331)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:227)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate.execute(JpaTemplate.java:230)
    

here is the example:
this is the data model
@Entity
public class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<AB> abSet = new HashSet<>();

    
}

@Entity
public class B {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "b", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<AB> abSet = new HashSet<>();

    
}

@Entity
@IdClass(AB.ID.class) 
public class AB {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
    private A a;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
    private B b;

   @Getter
   @AllArgsConstructor
   @NoArgsConstructor
   public static class ID implements Serializable {

      private Long a;
      private Long b;

      //equals and hashcode goes here
   }
} 

here is the code that throws the exception:
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
AB ab = new AB();

a.getAbSet().add(ab);
b.getAbSet().add(ab);

ab.setA(a);
ab.setB(b);
aRepository.save(a);

this is running under a transaction so I was expecting hibernate to transitively persist everybody... but it fails throwing the exception mentioned above
am i doing something wrong?

The exception doesn't line up with the classes you've given, making it much more difficult for anyone to help you: what is the SHORT_CIRCUIT_INDICATOR in relation to the model you've provided, and the same goes for br.com.fisgar.crm.model.entities.PersonClientLead$ID.clientLead, but as it is complaining about reflection and not being able to set values in that class- remove lombok from the equation. You likely don't have all the accessors required generated

there is no "SHORT_CIRCUIT_INDICATOR " in any field of any class in the whole project... I can only assume that this SHORT_CIRCUIT stuff comes from some internal flag on hibernate

I created all getters and setters manually for the sake of testing you theory but it still gives the same result, If i turn the hibernate logs to trace i can even see that the right sql is produced [if i just copy paste in the database it works] but yet somehow hibernate is not correctly managing something in the dependency chain....
i would like very much it worked but the workaround is simple create B without the relationship before trying to save A

that is the root cause of the error
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field AB$ID.b to org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper$1

It is saying it cannot set AB.ID.b - do you have a setter or accessible field for the 'b' long property within that class? I honestly don't know why Hibernate has to bother with your ID class at all, but it seems to be. Maybe make it a class separate from the Entity class and make sure Hibernate can use reflection on it.

Is not a setter problem, the class has a setter and either way hibernate tries to use reflection to set the stuff... I've debugged a lot and as far as I understood because there is a series of cascade persist operation [in a cicle] A cascade peresist AB that cascade persist A and B that cascade persist AB..... as far I debugged hibernate gets into a sort off infinite loop while setting the newly got ID for all those classes, then at same time hibernate has a mechanism to identify these loops and throws an exception to avoid it...

The SHORT_CIRCUIT something is just the name of the flag hibernate uses to identify the infinite loop. Like i said before I, if i simple Save B [without any relationship] then add the relation ship and save A... the cascade operation works fine and everything is saved.... it might be a bug on hibernate or a little detail in my configuration, but the workaround is so simple that i wont fight for 3 lines of code

You don't seem to have cascade options on the AB->B relationship set, so I don't see how B gets persisted (or how AB.b gets set then) which might be the issue with this code, and why it works when you first 'save' or persist B before setting the relationships.
